# Android - onActivityResult after navigation application ends

Tags: google-maps, navigation, feedback, onactivityresult

I launched an Intent to start GoogleMaps or Waze navigation.
If I'll launch the intent with onActivityResult, will I be able to get a feedback when my navigation is complete?
Is there any other way to get a feedback when the navigation ends?

My Code:

LAUNCHING GOOGLEMAPS

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr="+ latitudeCurr + "," +longitudeCurr+"&daddr="+destLatitude+","+destLongitude));        
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps","com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivityForResult(intent,5);
```

CATCHING THE RESULT

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode==5)
    Toast.makeText(this, "GoogleMap "+resultCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

It always returns resultCode 0 when I close GoogleMap not matter what the GoogleMap app did.

Thanks!!

Comment: post your code what you have tried..

Comment: Added the code to the question

Answer (score 0):

You can start any activity via startActivityForResult() but only if the activity is meant for that way of being started and does set a result code before finishing, will you receive different result codes.
In your case this does not seem to be the case.